# How do I generate concatenated fibonacci numbers in C?

Tags: c

Task is that function needs to print first n fibonacci nums in a new string:Example,for n = 10 function returns string "11235813213456"..Not sure why is this not totally working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* Fibonacci(int n)
{
    char s[50];
    char *x = malloc(1000);
    int f1 = 0, f2 = 1, i;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        sprintf(s, "%d ", f2);
        strcat(x,s);
        int next = f1 + f2;
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = next;
    }
    return x;
}

int main(void)
{
    char* fib = Fibonacci(10);
    printf("%s\n", fib);
    free(fib);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And how is it not working?

Comment: `malloc` does _not_ guarantee an EOS (i.e. 0) in the `x` buffer. Hence, `x` may have random data in it. Either use `calloc` or add `*x = 0;` before the loop. Otherwise, your `strcat` may produce random results because it scans the first arg (e.g. `x`) looking for the string end.

Comment: You should probably add some bound-checking to that `x` string if it can get over 999 characters.

Comment: @urica Lakić To output fibonacci numbers in one line does not mean to pack them in a string.

Comment: There  is no reason to malloc a constant value and never relocate it. Why not `char x[1000];`?

Comment: @Asadefa because it would go out of life/scope. The problem with the few 10 numbers is as Craig Estey says. You cannot concatenate to an uninitialised string.

Comment: @WeatherVane then why not make it static?

Comment: Also what is your expected output?

Comment: @jarmod my output is :-Xn11235813213455...needs to be in string and "11235813213456"

Comment: @Asadefa because I assume the OP wants the function to allocate the buffer and return it, instead of the caller allocating and passing the buffer. This allows any number of characters to be written to the string  (as opposed to a static limit), but the OP apparently didn't take care to do the bound-checking and reallocate the buffer.

Comment: @Jurica Lakić Pay attention to that 0 is also a fibonacci  number.

Comment: @DarkAtom It will still work what the OP wants if he makes it static instead of heap.

Comment: @Asadefa If he makes it static he has to declare it inside `main()` and pass it as a parameter which might not be what he wants (because `main()` has to be changed if he decides that he should make the array bounds larger or tighter).

Comment: @DarkAtom No, just try it yourself. Declare a static array in a function, and return it. It will work.

Comment: Nope, that is undefined behaviour, I don't care if it appears to work or not, the C standard says it. When you return a pointer to a local storage, that storage gets deallocated and you are actually returning a "dangling" pointer. Check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer

Comment: @DarkAtom It's not UB if it's declared `static`.  That gives it full program lifetime.

Comment: Ah you literally meant keyword static. Why would you ever declare something static if it's not absoloutely necessary (which most of the time isn't)? Static variables should only be used for keeping the state of the function (clearly not the case). And maybe you need to call the function multiple times, the calls would erase the previous answer... I am not going to give any more detail about why this is bad :))

Comment: You can't go very far with Fibonacci numbers, but beware of [Shlemiel algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this line:

```
char *x = malloc(sizeof *x * 1000);
// You should always add the sizeof expression because it doesn't hurt
// If you don't add it and you later change the type of x, the call will not work as intended.
```

Add this one:

```
x[0] = '\0';
```

The reason is because memory allocated with `malloc` isn't guaranteed to be filled with zeroes (but `strcat` needs the first character to be null when the string is empty or it results in UB). Alternatively, you can replace the call to `malloc` with a call to `calloc`, but it might be slower.

Also, even though you aren't doing any bound-checking in your code, I would advise you (assuming you are using C99 or later) to replace `sprintf` with `snprintf`. You should never use `sprintf` if you can at all avoid it:

```
snprintf(x, sizeof s / sizeof *s, "%d", f2);
```

EDIT: Since you apparently want the output to be enclosed in ", let me show you the whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* Fibonacci(int n)
{
    char s[50];
    char *x = malloc(1000);
    x[0] = '\"';
    x[1] = '\0';
    int f1 = 0, f2 = 1, i;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        snprintf(s, sizeof s / sizeof *s, "%d", f2);
        strcat(x,s);
        int next = f1 + f2;
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = next;
    }
    strcat(x, "\"");
    return x;
}

int main(void)
{
    char* fib = Fibonacci(10);
    printf("%s\n", fib);
    free(fib);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is better but output is still not in string " "....like this  "11235813213456"

Comment: You want the numbers to have no spaces between them? Remove the space in the "%d " in the `sprintf` call!

Comment: The function returns the newly created string! Output is in new string "11235813213456" Not just nums:11235813213456

Comment: I do not understand what you want. You want quotes around the output? Then just insert them by hand.

Comment: By the way the 10th Fibonacci number is 55 not 56 :)

Comment: You are right for 55 :)...I am not sure anymore how to explain what i need,my output needs to be in a string,numbers between apostrophe signs..This is full task:Write a function that for given n writes in the string of the first n Fibonacci numbers.
The function returns the newly created string.
Example: For n = 10 the function returns the string "11235813213455"...My output in this code is just 11235813213455 without ""

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you a full code with what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much :D

Comment: Good to use `snprintf();`.  Bad to use as `snprintf(s, 1000, "%d", f2);`.  Better as `snprintf(s, sizeof s, "%d", f2);`

Comment: Further, this concern about "You should never use sprintf if you can at all avoid it:"  and then `strcat(x,s);` which lacks any protection gives a mixed signal.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You are right about sizeof :). I guess the OP is learning the basics. Avoiding `strcat` requires custom code. `snprintf()` is just a matter of changing a function call, and it is good to use it from the start.

Comment: "snprintf() is just a matter of changing a function call" itself is insufficient as it lacks a check.  Sure code prevents a buffer overflow, yet now proceeds with a truncated results.  `snprintf(s, 17 ,  "Format the drive not"); system(s);`.  We are all learning at some level.

Comment: A side issue with `strcat()` is the the algorithm is most [inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61786186/how-do-i-generate-concatenated-fibonacci-numbers-in-c/61786358?noredirect=1#comment109300427_61786186).  Instead by keeping track of the overall length, the new `s` (with its sub-length from the return value of `sprintf()`) can get append efficiently.

Comment: As I told you, the OP is probably just learning the basics. I wanted to make a recommendation to use snprintf() instead of sprintf() because it is a better function (as it provides bound-checking). By no means did I try to make the code protected with all the known security measures, in which case the best recommendation is not to use the `sprintf()` family of functions at all. I was just trying to give the OP some tips to apply in the future. This question is not about buffer security at all.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I am not trying to change the OP's algorithm at all. The `sprintf()` triggers me just like `gets()` would, that's all. I didn't try to make his code neither secure nor efficient.